# JqGrid doesn't display JSON data

Tags: json, jsp, jqgrid

I have written code in JSP and used JSON object for displaying data in JqGrid.

I know my JSON object has data (I've log it's content) but it's not displaying in JqGrid. When I copied the JSON data into JSON string, it is getting loaded and successfully displaying in Jqgrid.

This is my JSP code:

```
JSONObject responcedata = new JSONObject();   
responcedata.put("total",totalrow);     
responcedata.put("page",cpage);     
responcedata.put("records",rcount);    
Report obj = new Report(); 
responcedata = obj.ReportGrid(responcedatal); 
System.out.println(responcedata);
```

This is the content of my JSON object:

> {"total":"21″,"rows":[{"cell":["HS","H","10","5","G","9288"],"id":"1″},{"cell":["",null,null,null,"G","2099"],"id":"2″},{"cell":["HS","F","3","53","G","86578"],"id":"3″},{"cell":["HS","F","7","26","G","8268"],"id":"4″},{"cell":["HS","F","8","54","G","221"],"id":"5″},{"cell":["HS","F","5","77","G","1020"],"id":"6″},{"cell":["HS","H","14","14","G","73334"],"id":"7″},{"cell":["HS","C","21","1","G&B","1512"],"id":"8″},{"cell":["HS","F","2","105","G","4960"],"id":"9″},{"cell":["HS","F","4","21","G","86889"],"id":"10″}],"records":11}

I used this JSON string and JqGrid is displaying data. When I use JSON object, the variable `responcedata` (in the code above) it only shows loading but data is never shown.

Comment: Post your code so some one can help you

Comment: You should modify your question and append JSON response and the JavaScript code which you use to create jqGrid. You can catch the exact JSON response of the server using Fiddler, Firebug, Developer Tools of IE or Chrome etc.

Comment: I have updated my question plz check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function callMe() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "action name",
        data : {}
    }).done(function(data) {

                // dat has list there is 5 column (id,fname,lname,username,password)

        var len = data.length;

        var t="";
        for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
                var id =  data[i].id;
                var fname =  data[i].fname;
                var lname =  data[i].lname;
                var username =  data[i].username;
                var password =  data[i].password;                      
                t+="<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+fname+"</td><td>"+lname+"</td><td>"+username+"</td><td>"+password+"</td></tr>"
         } 

         print(t,data);
    });
}

function print(t, data) {
    document.getElementById("welcometext").innerHTML = t;   
}
```

in html:

```
 <table id="welcometext" border="1">

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included another Jsp in the Jsp file which contains json data.
I removed that include line. Now it is working fine.